# How do I understand the Hibernate validator semantics

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have been reading the documentation of Hibernate validator and I stumbled upon this code snippet:

```
Class<?>[] groups() default { };
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
```

Here `groups()` and `payload(`) are attributes of an annotation.

I do not understand how these are actually attributes and yet have the semantics of a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faisal bhat. About your question, I found in this link [Oracle documentation for annotation types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html), that syntax of annotation type must be according to the specification. I hope this helps.